# Searching for upper and lower case characters

Tags: html, special-characters

So I basically need to reformat a BUNCH of HTML. The editor I'm using is called "TextWrangler" for mac (if it matters). The editor responds to characters such as '\t' and '\r'. So I was wondering if there's a special character representation for "any character within A and z" (I hope that makes sense).

Anyways, thanks for reading this and hopefully it's coherent, haha.

-Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the editor you mention [knows regular expressions](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/textwranglerpower.html) (and perl flavor in particular).  So in the find-and-replace function you can use `\w` to match any text character  (but that also includes 0-9) or the character class `[A-Za-z]` to match just letters.

Comment: Hey, I have another question. If I use \w or [A-Za-z], I will obviously replace the character. Is there any way to replace the character, then add that exact same character back in?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's fine, I found a work-around. Thank you so much, you were extremely helpful.